# Why was the interview-questions tag removed?

Tags: discussion, tags, meta-tags

The interview-questions tag was "Removed as part of 'The great Stack Overflow tag/question cleanup of 2012.'"  Why is this?  Is there another StackExchange site for these types of questions (e.g. Code Golf)?  If there is not, is there an alternate way of getting a list of these types of questions?

I've noticed that there are questions still being asked and tagged with this.  Should they be getting migrated?

I would look up the 'why', but it seems that [The great Stack Overflow tag/question cleanup of 2012](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/128315/the-great-stack-overflow-tag-question-cleanup-of-2012) was deleted.

Comment: It's a [meta tag](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/the-death-of-meta-tags/).

Comment: The downvote was uncalled for -- at least I tried to research.  @Servy: You could post that as the answer, I didn't realize those types of tags were frowned upon.

Comment: The down votes were likely just because the DV'ers disagreed with the implication that such questions are OK. I am not sure such an implication really exists myself, I should note, but I can imagine someone seeing it. Personally, I have upvoted this question simply because you have asked it; because you are looking to find out the *why*.

Comment: From the deleted post: "interview-questions - 2297 (review vote/flag for possibly being NC)"

Comment: This is a disappointment.  The combination of the algorithm and interview-questions tags were one of my favorite searches on the site.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As discussed in [this blog post](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/the-death-of-meta-tags/), meta tags are discouraged on this site.  This tag is clearly a meta tag in that it is not describing the content of the question, but rather the context of the question.  The easy test is to ask yourself if this could realistically be the only tag for a question, and that really isn't the case.  The link goes in depth, but one of the problems listed with meta tags are that so frequently mis-used (often because their very nature makes their definition ambiguous).

Comment: Makes sense. :) In the context of StackOverflow, I usually associate the idea of an 'interview question' as a programming challenge, but that's my own interpretation, not the meaning.

Comment: @Darthfett Many interviewers give real, actual problems as interview questions (and people try to tag them accordingly).  Those programming problems also come up a lot as homework questions (another meta tag).

Comment: Why delete interview-questions but keep homework? Homework is clearly a meta-tag. [I came over to meta just to ask what tag to tag an interview question to show it was appropriate to hint rather than answer. Homework seemed closest but wrong.] Is the homework tag discouraged?

Comment: @AndrewC There has been a LOT of debate over whether to keep [tag:homework] or not.  In the end, because so many people saw value in the tag despite the fact that it's a meta tag, the decision was made to not require homework questions to have the homework tag, but to allow the tag to exist and to have the person asking the question use it if they choose to.