# Where'd that tag go?

Tags: support, tags, notifications

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why was the interview-questions tag removed?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/142869/why-was-the-interview-questions-tag-removed)

I admit, I've been gone from here for a while. Now that I've come back to visit, I noticed that one of the tags I follow is gone without a trace. No, it isn't about matrices, it's [interview-questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/interview-questions). I click on my side bar of favorite tags and no questions arise.

What happened? And, more importantly, shouldn't some sign-post have been left for me to follow letting me know that fate of the tag?

Comment: This may help: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/142869/why-was-the-interview-questions-tag-removed

Comment: I don't know most of this, but as for your last question, as far as I know there is no mechanism for associating information with non-existent tags. In other words, there is no place to leave a sign post.

Comment: Thanks, that does help with the immediate question, but the larger question of leaving sign posts still remains.

Comment: Unless you actually suggest something I can't see how this can be feature request.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd I (twice) suggested leaving a sign post of the former tag page.

Comment: No. "shouldn't some sign-post have been left for me to follow letting me know that fate of the tag?" is not a request, it's at best a discussion. The main question here is also totally different. Posting new question as feature request asking to leave some trace when tag is removed is best in my opinion.